# get the return value of an arrow function using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have this arrow function:

```
saveNewPermissions = (newGroupPermissions, groupName) => {
    fetch(this.baseUrl + "/addPermission/group/" + groupName, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            permissions: newGroupPermissions
        })
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
            return json;
        });
}
```

That function above is on the Service file, and on my component class i want to get the json that the function returns:

```
 this.Service.save(newList, groupName)
```

I tried to do this but it didnt work:

```
 this.uaaService.saveNewPermissions(newList, groupName).then(response=>{
   console.log(response)
 })
```

Comment: Add `return fetch(.. code...)`

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',` is a **response** header, is has no place being on a request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

First of, you would want to return the Promise from the arrow function

```
saveNewPermissions = (newGroupPermissions, groupName) => {
  return fetch(...) // returns a Promise object
}
```

then if you expect `newList` to be an array, you want to do:

```
this.uaaService.saveNewPermissions(newGroupPermissions, groupName).then((newListJSON) => {
  this.Service.save(newListJSON, groupName);
})
```